# Selenium xpath: Trying to get original url from archived link

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am working on a project, trying to scrape articles from archive websites. For example, below is an archive url and the original url. I have the archive url. And I want to use Selenium to extract the original url.

Arhive url: `https://archive.is/xXAoL`

Original url: `https://beforeitsnews.com/eu/2021/08/breaking-germany-halts-all-covid-19-vaccines-says-they-are-unsafe-and-no-longer-recommended-2676130.html?fbclid=IwAR3JPcxNHlZ5eQHLyO2teh6_xcrerisBrCNeleOZz7qmxI7_pDJDBlEAIjU`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://archive.is/xXAoL"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
```

Any advice on how to get the original url?

*Method 1*

One thing that might work is that the canonical link is

```
https://archive.is/2021.09.07-145059/https://beforeitsnews.com/eu/2021/08/breaking-germany-halts-all-covid-19-vaccines-says-they-are-unsafe-and-no-longer-recommended-2676130.html?fbclid=IwAR3JPcxNHlZ5eQHLyO2teh6_xcrerisBrCNeleOZz7qmxI7_pDJDBlEAIjU
```

I could just strip out things up until the second https. However, that method is not working so looking for another method not relying on meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the *original url* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://archive.is/xXAoL')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='q'][value]"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://archive.is/xXAoL')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q'][@value]"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://beforeitsnews.com/eu/2021/08/breaking-germany-halts-all-covid-19-vaccines-says-they-are-unsafe-and-no-longer-recommended-2676130.html?fbclid=IwAR3JPcxNHlZ5eQHLyO2teh6_xcrerisBrCNeleOZz7qmxI7_pDJDBlEAIjU
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I am getting `NameError: name 'EC' is not defined`...what is EC supposed to be?

Comment: Okay the imports fixed that. I still get "NameError: name 'by_CSS_SELECTOR' is not defined"

Comment: It should be `By.CSS_SELECTOR`

Comment: Using xpath and is working well, scraped about a hundred so far